# Visual Studio Connection String- Relative file path?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database, visual-studio-2010

I have built a database using visual studio 2010. In my dataaccess file i wrote my connection string

```
@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SOFTWARE\Database\persondb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
```

as you can see my database is in

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Software\Database\persondb.mdf
```

My solution is

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Software\Management System\Management System.sln
```

Connection String of a database has to be changed every time it transferred from one pc to another. I dont want to do that. So i tried to change the absolute file path to relative file path(regarding to my .sln file). I changed my connection string like this-

```
@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=..\Database\persondb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
```

but it didn't work. So what is my problem? windows usually recognizes  *..* as *directory up* command. Is relative file path dont work with connection strings?

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that at runtime you're executing out of:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Software\Management System\bin\Debug
```

so the relative path from there is:

```
..\..\..\Database ...
```

However, there is a more fundamental problem with this approach. That only works in development. When deploying the system you won't have the `Database` folder three directories above you, it will actually be a sub-directory.

A more appropriate approach may be to make a `Database` folder in your solution, put the database in there, and then set it to `Copy Always`. The connection string would then be:

```
Database\ ...
```

and that would work in both development and production.

Comment: oh thnx, let me try this

Comment: no ..\ symbol doesn't seem to work. neither does nesting database folder under solution. well i guess i have to use absolute path always :(

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to write absolute paths, you need to put your database file in `App_Data` folder and add following connection string in `web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="PersonDBCS" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\persondb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

where `|DataDirectory|` points to `App_Data` folder.

Then you can access it this way:

```
using System.Configuration;
...
string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PersonDBCS"].ConnectionString
```

Comment: well, i am using windows form so there is no App_Data folder in my solution. So what does |DataDirectory| mean for me? debug folder??